# qgis refresh button for attributeactions

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

```
QgsVectorLayer* vLyr=static_cast<QgsVectorLayer*>(aktLayer->qgsLayer);
vLyr->actions()->addAction(QgsAction::ActionType::OpenUrl, "Link im Webbrowser öffnen", "[% "+sAttribute+" %]" , ":/images/images/hotlink.png", false);
vLyr->actions()->setDefaultAction(vLyr->actions()->size()-1);
```

In my plugin after loading a layer to mapregistry i add with the code above an attribute-action to the layer. But i can't use it, because the button in attributes-toolbar is disabled. Looking at the layerproperties-dialog all seems to be ok and only after clicking 'OK' (not 'Apply') in the dialog the button in toolbar gets enabled and all works fine. 
What function do I have to call to reload/refresh the attributes-toolbar in QGIS? Does anybody know this?

EDIT:

found the method `"void QgisApp::refreshFeatureActions()"` which maybe could solve my problem but how can i access this class from my cpp-plugin?

EDIT:

The final solution for me is the following:

```
QgsVectorLayer* vLyr=static_cast<QgsVectorLayer*>(aktLayer->qgsLayer);

QToolBar* attributeToolbar= mQGisIface->mainWindow()->findChild<QToolBar*>("mAttributesToolBar");

vLyr->actions()->addAction(QgsAction::ActionType::OpenUrl, "Link im Webbrowser öffnen", "[% "+sAttribute+" %]" , ":/images/images/hotlink.png", false);
vLyr->actions()->setDefaultAction(vLyr->actions()->size()-1);

QgsMapLayerAction * mapAction=new QgsMapLayerAction("Link im Webbrowser öffnen", attributeToolbar, aktLayer->qgsLayer, QgsMapLayerAction::Target::AllActions);//, new QIcon(":/images/images/hotlink.png"));
QgsMapLayerActionRegistry::instance()->addMapLayerAction(mapAction);
QgsMapLayerActionRegistry::instance()->removeMapLayerAction(mapAction);
```

I have to remove the QgsMapLayerAction because it doesn't know that it is an OpenURL an so it is empty. But only adding an entry to the QgsMapLayerActionRegistry emits a signal to check the toolbar availibility.
I don't know why I have no access to QgisApp-class, can't include qgisapp.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this help you since this is for python. Why not add the action to attributes toolBar.

```
attributeToolBar = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'mattributeToolBar')

action = QtGui.QAction(parent)

attributeToolBar.addAction(action)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave me the right hint. But was little bit confusing because QGis needs to be tricked a little bit. First I get the toolbar analog to your code: `QToolBar* attributeToolbar= mQGisIface->mainWindow()->findChild<QToolBar*>("mAttributesToolBar");` But I'll have to create a QgsMapLayerAction to add the toolbar, then qgis refreshes the toolbar, but shoes me 2 actions, one of them is empty, so Ill have to remove the MapLayerAction and it works fine.